# Testing validation: formErrors div with no input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

The expected number of <li> tags (error messages) should be six, but I am only getting three. Does anyone have a clue about how I can fix my code? Here is what I am basically trying to do:

- Perform the following form validations in the order provided and display all error messages that apply:

  - Ensure a full name with a length greater than or equal to 1 was provided

    - Otherwise, display "Missing full name."
  - Ensure that an email address was provided and that the email address matches the regular expression:
    `/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}$/`

    - Otherwise, display "Invalid or missing email address."
  - Ensure the password has 10 to 20 characters

    - Otherwise, display "Password must be between 10 and 20 characters."
  - Ensure the password contains at least one lowercase character (use a regular expression)

    - Otherwise, display "Password must contain at least one lowercase character."
  - Ensure the password contains at least one uppercase character (use a regular expression)

    - Otherwise, display "Password must contain at least one uppercase character."
  - Ensure the password contains at least one digit (use a regular expression)

    - Otherwise, display "Password must contain at least one digit."
  - Ensure the password and confirmation password match

    - Otherwise, display "Password and confirmation password don't match."

```
"use strict";

function checkForm() {
  const fullNameInput = document.getElementById("fullName");
  const emailInput = document.getElementById("email");
  const passwordInput = document.getElementById("password");
  const passwordConfirmInput = document.getElementById("passwordConfirm");
  const formErrorsDiv = document.getElementById("formErrors");

  // Reset errors and remove classes
  formErrorsDiv.innerHTML = "";
  fullNameInput.classList.remove("error");
  emailInput.classList.remove("error");
  passwordInput.classList.remove("error");
  passwordConfirmInput.classList.remove("error");

  // Error messages in <li> tags
  const errorMessages = {
    fullName: "Missing full name.",
    email: "Invalid or missing email address.",
    passwordLength: "Password must be between 10 and 20 characters.",
    passwordLowercase: "Password must contain at least one lowercase character.",
    passwordUppercase: "Password must contain at least one uppercase character.",
    passwordDigit: "Password must contain at least one digit.",
    passwordConfirm: "Password and confirmation password don't match."
  };

  const errors = [];

  // Check full name
  if (fullNameInput.value.trim().length === 0) {
    errors.push("fullName");
    fullNameInput.classList.add("error");
  }

  // Check email
  const emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}$/;
  if (!emailRegex.test(emailInput.value.trim())) {
    errors.push("email");
    emailInput.classList.add("error");
  }

  // Check password
  const password = passwordInput.value;
  const passwordRegex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{10,20}$/;
  if (password.length < 10 || password.length > 20) {
    errors.push("passwordLength");
    passwordInput.classList.add("error");
  } else if (!password.match(/[a-z]/)) {
    errors.push("passwordLowercase");
    passwordInput.classList.add("error");
  } else if (!password.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
    errors.push("passwordUppercase");
    passwordInput.classList.add("error");
  } else if (!password.match(/\d/)) {
    errors.push("passwordDigit");
    passwordInput.classList.add("error");
  }

  // Check password confirmation
  if (passwordConfirmInput.value !== password) {
    errors.push("passwordConfirm");
    passwordConfirmInput.classList.add("error");
  }

  if (errors.length > 0) {
    // Display error messages
    const errorList = document.createElement("ul");
    errors.forEach(error => {
      const errorMessage = document.createElement("li");
      errorMessage.innerText = errorMessages[error];
      errorList.appendChild(errorMessage);
    });
    formErrorsDiv.appendChild(errorList);
    formErrorsDiv.classList.remove("hide");
  } else {
    formErrorsDiv.classList.add("hide");
  }
}

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  checkForm();

  // Prevent default form action. DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears here:

```
    if (password.length < 10 || password.length > 20) {
        errors.push("passwordLength");
        passwordInput.classList.add("error");
    } else if (!password.match(/[a-z]/)) {
        errors.push("passwordLowercase");
        passwordInput.classList.add("error");
    } else if (!password.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
        errors.push("passwordUppercase");
        passwordInput.classList.add("error");
    } else if (!password.match(/\d/)) {
        errors.push("passwordDigit");
        passwordInput.classList.add("error");
    }
```

Change it to:

```
    if (password.length < 10 || password.length > 20) {
        errors.push("passwordLength");
        passwordInput.classList.add("error");
    }
    if (!password.match(/[a-z]/)) {
        errors.push("passwordLowercase");
        passwordInput.classList.add("error");
    }
    if (!password.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
        errors.push("passwordUppercase");
        passwordInput.classList.add("error");
    }
    if (!password.match(/\d/)) {
        errors.push("passwordDigit");
        passwordInput.classList.add("error");
    }
```